# GHC 7.0.3 denies to show 2^1000 as a normalized double - outputs "infinity"

Tags: haskell, floating-point, double, infinity

I have the following output - and I am surprised. Any help why "my Doubles" seem to be so low?

> > Prelude GHC.Float> floatRange (0.5e1000::Double)
> >
> > (-1021,1024)
> >
> > Prelude GHC.Float> show (0.5e1000::Double)
> >
> > "Infinity"

The exponent 1000 seems to be quite far away from the 1024 limit (as I expected IEEE to contain this ::Double).

I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 7):

Most likely, `floatRange` is returning the range of the *binary* (base-2) exponent. You are setting a base-10 exponent of 1024 here, so you're asking the base-2 exponent to reach 3402 or so.

Comment: Ouch I feel stupid now :| Thats true of course - thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

`0.5e1000` does not mean "2^1000".  It means "0.5 * 10^1000", which actually is well outside the range of representable double-precision values.